# Node.js JavaScript Creating Base model and extending it

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, model-view-controller

I am trying to create s Base Model and extend models from it, but when i call DataModel it calls the function of UsersModel...

This is how i do the call:

```
var model = new(require('../models/DataModel'));

module.exports = PrivateController.extend({
name : 'Wall',
content : null,
run : function(type, req, res){        
    model.get(function(err, result){
        //WHEN THIS GETS CALLED -> DISPLAYS 'users' and should me xyz from DataModel
    }
```

});

Base.js

```
module.exports = function(db) {
this.db = db;
};
module.exports.prototype = {
extend: function(properties) {
    var Child = module.exports;
    Child.prototype = module.exports.prototype;
    for(var key in properties) {
        Child.prototype[key] = properties[key];
    }
    return Child;
}
```

DataModel:

```
var Model = require("./Base"),
model = new Model();


var DataModel = model.extend({
    collection_name: 'xyz',
get: function(callback) {
    console.log(this.collection_name); // THIS SHOULD DISPLAY 'xyz'
}
});


 module.exports = DataModel;
```

Instead of showing DataModel collection name i get it from here:

UserModel.js

```
var Model = require("./Base"),
model = new Model();

var UserModel = model.extend({
collection_name: 'users',
get: function(callback, email, password) {
    console.log(this.collection_name); //DISPLAY users
},



module.exports = UserModel;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got the code from for that `extend` function but it's horribly incorrect.

I've formatted it a bit better so we can see the issues:

```
var Base = function(db) {
    this.db = db;
};

Base.prototype = {
    extend: function(properties) {
        var Child = Base; // what?
        Child.prototype = Base.prototype; // what?
        for(var key in properties) {
            Child.prototype[key] = properties[key];
        }
        return Child;
    }
};
```

In your extend function:

You're setting the child object to be a reference to the super object, thus you're effectively changing the super object, thus all other objects that rely on the super prototype will be affected.

This is probably what you want to do:

```
var Base = function(db) {
    this.db = db;
};

Base.prototype = {
    extend: function(properties) {
        var Child = function(){
            Base.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        Child.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
        for(var key in properties) {
            Child.prototype[key] = properties[key];
        }
        return Child;
    }
};
```

For inheritance in node.js, personally I would just stick with [`util.inherits`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor). Have a read on [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to view more inheritance examples.

Comment: I managed to put it to work by changing the line "Child.prototype = module.exports.prototype;" to: "Child.prototype = new module.exports(this.db) "... does it look correct now? By the way the code is from here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-complete-mvc-website-with-expressjs--net-34168

Comment: Yes, `Child.prototype = new module.exports(this.db)` will work, but it will also execute the super constructor, which you only want to do when creating a new instance, not when extending. This is why you use `Object.create` rather.

Comment: BTW, that article is total rubbish IMO. His extend code and his tests are atrocious.

Comment: Seriously man, don't follow that article. It's full of fail, and will confuse you.

Comment: haha Thanks i am making my first nodejs project, but i am not totally following it, just took "Base controller" and "Base model" idea...if you have any good references(better examples), please show me

Comment: For simple object inheritance (using "base classes"), just look at http://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

Comment: I've created some examples for you which show how to use util.inherits or Object.create: https://gist.github.com/badsyntax/9970212 Have a good day.